# Is it possible to align my div elements vertically?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have three separate vertical columns, is there a way I can change my code to make the columns vertical instead of horizontal (like they are now).

```css
.cols {
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 50%;
  min-width: 90%;
  background: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.cols div {
  position: relative;
  background: #232323;
}
.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
  <div class="col">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Currently I have three horizontal boxes stretching across an outside container, I would like the three boxes to be evenly set out in vertical columns, if that makes sense.

Comment: Columns are columns and orders from left to right. If you need rows, use `display: table-row;`. Or don't redeclare `display` property for `divs` at all.

Comment: This is actually very strange, because on my webpage the cells are split so they are each their own row (one on top of the other). But my code snippet shows them side by side, which is what I want, let me look into this

Comment: @SergeyKhalitov Where am i re declaring display for a div?

Comment: Are you using a framework like Bootstrap?

Comment: @Twtheo, here `.cols { display: table; }` and here `.col { display: table-cell; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, this can be done using `flex`:

```css
.cols {
  min-height: 50%;
  min-width: 90%;
  background: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cols div {
  background: #232323;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
  <div class="col">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have an error when trying to write

display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;

Comment: "Error in parsing value 'display'". Did you change the .col class?

Comment: @Twtheo I removed the `.col` class as you don't need to use `display: table-cell;` with `flex`.

Comment: Alright, and the error (I guess it's actually a warning, but I don't think that part is even running)? It has a problem with {display: -webkit-flex;}

Comment: @Twtheo Are you testing this locally or through a webhost?

Comment: I am doing this through a webhost